Github deploy code Fails where Func app in Vnet - auth error using OIDC
Regarding section Deploy a Service Bus trigger and HTTP trigger I get auth error IP Forbidden to to deploy the code via github. Since both storage and func app are behind private end points is github expected to successfully be authorized even with a managed identity since it's outside the vnet?
Func app settings:

I confirm github repo yml file has the correct secrets, both attempted automatically generated and manually entered.
I am using a service principal federated credentials for deployment with RBAC storage and website contributor roles assigned at resource group level.

yaml file
Thrown error at deployment:
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Execution Exception (state: PublishContent) (step: Invocation)
Error:   When request Azure resource at PublishContent, zipDeploy : Failed to use /home/runner/work/_temp/temp_web_package_045189892229569706.zip as ZipDeploy content
Error:     Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)


Suggested alternative zip deploy also fails because it is outside the vnet. Unfortunately I do not have the flexibility to setup my own self-hosted github.

Making it private will not let you push from outside (say Github) -- you need to go through the tutorial you posted (and set the Settings tab as they suggest) to make it work with Github. Otherwise as they state in that page you posted - Enabling private endpoints on a function app also makes the Source Control Manager (SCM) site publicly inaccessible.

Hello @AlexD. I followed the tutorial which sets the func app behind a vnet. I used the same deployment settings but with a public python repo, I understand the nature of the repo code deployed should not make a difference, it's rather getting authenticated for deployment. Indeed SCM is inaccessible, how is it accesible for the tutorial with the func app behind a vnet?

Did you add the application settings WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16, WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1 and WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1 in the function app?

Also check the article if it helps.

Thanks a bunch @Pravallika KV, github can now az login but can't deploy with forbidden 401. I've updated the post.

Can you try enabling access from virtual networks? Refer Image.

Hello @PravallikaKV I can confirm I can deploy the same repo without vnet.

With public access disabled?

with public access enabled and without a vnet, reproduced without vnets

Hello @PravallikaKV I am now replicating your image to "Enable from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" in the function app, what rule should I add? The rule does not let me choose any available subnet like your kvpnet - image here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YiUuAvhoN-Jq1EedkiF0g74TGd_PoDM9/view?usp=sharing . Thank you

Select Virtual network instead of Ipv4.

Thank you @PravallikaKV . I've added rule to enabled vnet access of funcapp inbound subnet. Does the inbound subnet of the storage account need to be added too ? - please see snapshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pw4UGVRaeh48_VIE-sTT7Ti5bXpeQNOu/view?usp=sharing

without enabling storage account subnet as per my comment above, it has deployed ! Thank you so much @PravallikaKV :)

Glad it worked. Can I post it as an answer?

Absolutely, well done and thank you so much @PravallikaKV :)

To deploy a function to Azure function functionapp which is configured with Private endpoints, you need add the below application settings in the function app.
WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1


To resolve the 403 forbidden error, selectEnable from selected virtual networks and IP addresses in the Function app=>Networking and add a rule to enable vnet access.


I have deployed the function to Azure:



References:
Function App Deployment Failed - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Extremely helpful, works, thank you. I note I didn't need setting WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER=168.63.129.16
